# How to Pandas groupby Index and Column for aggregate result

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Time column has been indexed and below code is working fine for 24 hours.but I need same result for 7 days but for specific single port. i.e 
57621 and single IP wise.

SO how to get group by results day wise for single port 57621 and single IP wise ???

```
Dst_Port  Packet_leng Time Source_IP
53 80 03/10/2019 15:01:42 172.16.1.9
53 80 03/11/2019 15:01:42 172.16.1.9
138 258 03/12/2019 15:01:43 172.16.2.1
138 235 03/13/2019 15:01:43 172.16.2.1
57621 76 03/14/2019 15:01:43 172.16.1.9
57621 76 03/15/2019 15:03:29 157.7.235.92
57621 68 03/16/2019 15:05:33 172.16.0.1


(df.groupby(df.index.hour)['Packet_length']
   .agg({'Packet': ['min','max','mean', 'median', 'std']})
   .plot(kind='bar',title='Day - Hourly Packets', legend=True, ax=ax))
```

below code output graph has been aggregates 7 days result. but I need day wise separately for 7 days for day wise.

```
ax = plt.gca()
df[df.Dst_Port.eq(57621)].groupby('Dst_Port') . 
['Packet_length'].agg({'Packet':['sum','min','max','mean', 
'median', 
'std']}).plot(kind='bar',title='Destination Portwise Packets', 
legend=True, ax=ax)

plt.xlabel('Destination Port')
plt.ylabel('Packet')
plt.title('Destination Portwise Packets')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Lack of sample data in text form really discourages people to help you.

Comment: Hi Quang, I cant understand you pls. can you let me know what can I change here

Comment: Instead of the picture of your data, you should copy the output and paste it as text.

Comment: Yes added text format

Comment: I am confused. `df[df.SomeColumnName.eq(SomeNumber)]` seems to be intended to filter for a particular port. Why is there then need to group by Port, of which there is only 1?  To filter for days, we still don't really know what the format is. Grouped by weekday-hour to see the progression of daily profiles over a week, or the aggregation by weekday-metrics over all hours?   What you can do to help us help you, is to provide a mcve <- https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . I doubt anyone has the grit to try and construct a relevant example dataframe by themselves..

Comment: Issues has been resolved due to following codes has been meet my purposes. df[df.Dst_Port.eq(57621)].groupby(['Source_IP', pd.Grouper(key='Time', freq='D')])['Packet_length'].agg({'Packet':['min','max','mean', 'median', 'std']}).plot(kind='line',title=' Month - Single Portwise Packets', legend=True, ax=ax)